# How to rotate a table with caption and have a section name in the same page

Tags: sectioning, floats, captions, rotating

I need to rotate a table with caption, but I need to have a section name in top of the same page.

Already tried with `sidewaystable`, but it reserves a entire page only for the table.

Then I've tried using `sideways`, but the caption didn't work with that.

I've also tried using `rotatebox`, but I couldn't make it work...

Tried: `ctable`, `landscape` ...

No success at all...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you showed what failed in the a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: To be honest, I would put the caption non-rotated. But even better, I would not mix rotated and non-rotated content on one page unless there's a really good reason.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,nonFloat]%
{}%
{\begin{tabular}{ll}
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c \\
\end{tabular}}%
{A rotated table}%
{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]